# gnuplot package not found

Tags: apt

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.1. I tried installing Gnupolot, gfortran using sudo ap get install, but the terminal shows 'unable to locate package gnuplot-x11' and 'The following package cannot be authenticated'.

Answer (score 2):

For `gnuplot`, do you have [`universe` repository enabled](https://askubuntu.com/a/148653/16395)? Should be there:

```
[romano:~] % apt-cache policy gnuplot-x11
gnuplot-x11:
  Installed: 4.6.4-2
  Candidate: 4.6.4-2
  Version table:
 *** 4.6.4-2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`gfortran`, instead, is in `main`; should be installed without any problem:

```
[romano:~] % apt-cache policy gfortran   
gfortran:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Version table:
     4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

...so please edit your question to report the exact errors you have.

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gfortran_4.8.2-1ubuntu6_i386.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Following error is coming:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: I am new to linux, hence am not able to understand things properly. When I type sudo apt-get install gfortran the following error come:E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gfortran_4.8.2-1ubuntu6_i386.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
PLEASE HELP.